# Wordpress how to check how many post available in particular category?

Tags: php, wordpress

Using cat id how can I check how many post available within this category, if post is not available then return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [get_term_by()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

```
$result = get_term_by( 'id', 0, 'category' );
echo count( $result );
```

replace the `0` with your required category ID.

Answer (score 0):

it may help you check it..

```
<?php
$postsInCat = get_term_by($field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter );
$postsInCat = $postsInCat->count;
echo $postsInCat;
?>
```

Comment: `$postInCat` would be an array. `$postsInCat->count` is meaningless.